# Codeigniter pagination conceptual problem

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a page /discussion and I want to implement pagination in it. Now, I want that for the first time the page should load as /discussion, which means that this act as if it was /discussion/page/1. For the other page the url will be /discussion/page/$pagenumber.

Now, the problem is index(). Normally, I initialize all the page data in the index() and then load the view with the initialized data. But, here I’ll have to initialize default page stuff in index() and then the pagination stuff in page(). So, is there a way of sending another set of data from page() to the view? I don’t want to load the view since it will be loaded by the index().

However, I think it is not possible to do what I mentioned above. So, maybe I should keep my index() empty and do all the initialization in the page() and then load the view there. What do you say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need both the "page" and "index" methods, just use a [route](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

Using an `index()` method and dropping the `page()` method:

```
$route['discussion/page/(:num)'] = 'discussion/index/$1';
```

`/discussion` still gives you page 1, requesting `discussion/page/32` will map to `discussion/index/32`

This assumes you're grabbing the page number as an argument (url segment), like so:

```
function index ($page = 1) {}
```

If you are doing something else, a route is still appropriate, maybe just not the one provided.

Comment: I tried this and it seems to work a bit. But, then all the image file paths change. I am fetching images as ../images/imagename.jpg but after these pagination changes I have to fetch them using ../../images/imagename.jpg.

Adding this route does something to the paths :(.

Comment: The problem truly lies in the use of relative paths for images. Use full urls, `/absolute/paths/to-image.jpg`, or just use the `img()` function. You can't rely on relative paths when you are dealing with dynamic urls.

Comment: Cool. That worked :). One more thing: The first page in the pagination area is /discussions/page. How can I change it to /discussions/page/1 or just /discussions?

Comment: You mean `/discussions/page` is the first link that the pagination generates?

Comment: Yeah `/discussions/page` is the first link. Should I add something like:

`function page(){ $this->index(1);}`

Comment: It wouldn't affect the link generated, or be necessary otherwise. If you use `1` as the default argument, `/discussions/page` should still give you page 1. It really depends on what exactly you want to happen, and what your config and controller look like. I don't know off the top of my head, other than to say I was unsatisfied with the default pagination library (little issues like this) and wrote my own version.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all your help :). I have added that function page() to my code it seems to work fine. I hope to tweak it in future when I am done with the complete application.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Blueboye: You may want another route, a redirect, or a different configuration for the pagination. Sorry I can't say what would be best for you.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to have a look at PEAR's awesome [Pager package](http://pear.php.net/package/Pager). It automatically generates a pager and gives you the correct indexes depending on the (GET) input variables.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what your problem is.

If you have a `index()` method you can set all the pagination information there, remember you have to tell the pagination library which uri segment will be using to get the page number, and that doesn't have anything to do with the `index()`.

There is no `page()` method in the controller, all of the pages are the same `index()` with a different set of paginated data, given by the uri_segment defined as the page number, that means all the stuff that is not related to the paginated queryset are intact through the pages.

Comment: So, how will the url look like (for different pages)?

Comment: It can look however you want, /discussions/index/2 or /discussions/index/page/2, (being 'discussions' the name of the controller and 'index' the method.
Note that if you want to remove `index` from the url and use only `page` you will have to set that url in the routes config file:
`$route['discussions/page/:any'] = "discussions/index/page/$1";`

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to have your page method decorate your index method. Without knowing more about the overall structure of the controller, there really isn't terribly much to say, but it sounds like the below will help:

```
function page( $pos )
{
    $this->index( $pos );
}

// a default parameter lets you ensure that this does not neet to have a page set.
function index( $pos = 0 )
{
   // when calling the DB (I'm guessing that is where the pagination really happens)
   // COUNT should be defined in the config if possible.
   $this->db->where/*... add more here...*/->limit( COUNT, $pos );
}
```

Realistically, you should look into your URI routing class or using the _resolve method, but this should do what you need it to.